Movie about a woman with a sword-shaped birthmark that marks her as the chosen one
I saw this movie on TV, just minutes of it. In the scene, there was a man, a woman, and an older man. It looked like the woman met the man recently and they brought her to the older man to meet. The older man sees a birthmark or tattoo on her body and said something about her being the chosen one for some purpose, and said they were looking for her.
The room was kind of in a dark setting filled with old mystical objects.
I don't remember this exactly, but the birthmark looked like a sword or something.
This movie must be from more than 6 to 7 years ago.

Welcome to SciFi.SE! Is there anything else you can remember about this film? When and where did you watch it? What language was it in? Anything at all that you can remember will be helpful to us.

And, other than "mystical objects", do you know if there was any fantasy aspect? If the objects seemed visibly magical (glowing, emitting strange colored smoke, emitting angelic choruses), that's a good match. If it's a room with a crystal ball and a stuffed alligator hung from the ceiling, it might be entirely mundane.

FWIW, I don't seen an example with a sword birthmark at https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BirthmarkOfDestiny

i watched it 6 to 7 years ago, i saw it in hindi dubbed version, mystical objects i dont remember but there can be a fantasy element in the movie

Was it some kind of East setting? Where was that mark located?

The defender/avenger in the 1981 Heavy Metal had some such thing somewhere (her neck?).

Yes the Heavy Metal (1981) Defender/Avenger character (Taarna) had a birthmark on her neck in the shape of a sword with hooks (almost looking like a cross) https://www.tylisaari.com/models/gallery/hm/anubis/tarnstrip011.JPG BUT, this was a animated movie (Cartoon) and I am sure the OP would have mentioned that.

This may be Call Girl of Cthulhu. It's not a sword birthmark but other details fit.

Virgin artist Carter wants desperately to lose his virginity, but only to the right person. He thinks he has found the right person in Riley, a call girl with a strange birthmark on her right buttock.
Carter's dreams of romance are soon ruined, as several Cthulhu-worshiping cultists of the Church of Starry Wisdom see this birthmark as a sign that Riley is destined to become the bride of Cthulhu and bear his child.



Not convinced that this is the sort of film that would be dubbed into Hindi and shown in India...

@F1Krazy, yeah I thought about that. It wasn't particularly risqué though, more a comedy/horror film.

nor definetly not this one. movie wast kind of chosen one movies like the girl was the chosen one kind of prophecy kind of movie, by the way this movie you suggested looks fun
